# template getter must return HTMLTemplateElement in polmer <google-map> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polymer, polymer-3.x

I am trying to use polymerjs3.0 google-map component but i am getting **template getter must return HTMLTemplateElement** error, can someone please post the code snippet on how to use polymer google-map component.

```js
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer';
import '@em-polymer/google-apis/google-maps-api.js';
import '@em-polymer/google-map/google-map-marker.js';

class GoogleMap extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html ` <google-map fit-to-markers api-key="My Map Key"> 
          <google-map-marker latitude="37.78" longitude="-122.4" draggable="true">
          </google-map-marker> 
    </google-map> `;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('googlemap-page', GoogleMap);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a return statement in the template getter method, which returns a html tagged template:

```
static get template() {
    return html`<div>This is my template!</div>`;
//--^^^^^^-^^^^----Check for these two have to be present there.      
}
```

Comment: Can you add your polymer class code to your post? That would be nice to answer.

Comment: import {PolymerElement, html} from '@polymer/polymer';
import '@em-polymer/google-apis/google-maps-api.js';
import '@em-polymer/google-map/google-map-marker.js';


class GoogleMap extends PolymerElement {
static get template() {
  return html`
    <google-map fit-to-markers api-key="My Map Key">
      <google-map-marker latitude="37.78" longitude="-122.4" draggable="true"></google-map-marker>
    </google-map>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('googlemap-page', GoogleMap);

Comment: Could you please help me on this?